# ssl access to remote private docker-registry

Tags: nginx, openssl, docker-registry

trying to setup a private remote docker-registry  with nginx server , I get stuck with the SSL access to it ...

```
Get https://mydockerregistry.mydomain.com/v1/_ping: read tcp   
188.166.114.100:443: i/o timeout. If this private registry supports 
only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--
insecure-registry mydockerregistry.mydomain.com` to the daemon's 
arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's 
CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate 
at /etc/docker/certs.d/mydockerregistry.mydomain.com/ca.crt
```

For testing purposes, I am using a self-signed certificate ( should I not ?)
and I wrote in  /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydockerregistry.mydomain.com

```
    server { 
      server_name mydockerregistry.mydomain.com;

      listen 443 ssl; 
      ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt; 
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
      ssl_ciphers 'AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH::!EECDH+aRSA+RC4:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS';
      ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
      ssl_stapling on;
      ssl_stapling_verify on;
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
      add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
```

what's wrong with my SSL set up... ?

Answer (score 0):

I moved to private registry v2 installation with certificate ( not self-signed)
the API ping check is now  https://mydockerregistry.mydomain.com/v2/
and it return an empty JSON {}

it seems self-signed certificates are not accepted ,